# Protractor capture screenshot on failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing, webpage-screenshot

I have written below code in **afterEach** method to capture screenshot on **failure**

```
afterEach(function() {
  var passed = jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.results().passed();
  if (!passed) {
    browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
      //capturing screenshot here

    };
  }
});
```

But while executing getting below error..

```
 Message:
   Failed: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
 Stack:
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
```

how to remove above error...

Answer (score 1):

`currentSpec` is [not going to work](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/611) with `jasmine2`.

Please see if [`protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter) fits your use case.

There is also [`jasmine-test-container-support`](https://github.com/bpmn-io/jasmine-test-container-support) library that extends jasmine2 and provides you with all of the meta information you would need about the currently executed test.

Comment: Will look into jasmine-test-container-support

Comment: hi is there any way to find out the pass/fail status after execution?