# Protractor: Take screenshot on expect-failure

Tags: protractor

I know a lot has been written already, but I couldn't find a situation relating to an actual version of Protractor_5.3.0 and Jasmine_2.8.

Protractor offers an (inofficial?) how-to for taking a screenshot on expect-fail [here](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/screenshot).
But for some reasons, unknown to me, this doesn't work in my case (running Jasmine 2.8). I read somewhere, that they (jasmine) discontinued/discourage this way (intercepting the result).

Now I thought it should be possible to establish a `spyOnProperty()` for the result-object, but I'm unable to get it when I need it.
The idea is in `beforeAll` or `beforeEach` to establish the `spy` like this:

```
spyOnProperty("which Object?", "what property?").and.callFake(function(){
  //take screenshot and safe it
  //somehow let the test continue like "and.callThrough()"
}
```

Just as far as I understand the spies, it would stop the test execution.

My first approach was to use [Jasmine Reporter Interface](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/Reporter.html), but they don't offer a screenshot at the moment of failure. ... I can only access it in the `afterEach`, which isn't sufficient for me. (Reason: we have a objects.js-library containing specific command-sets for object-interactions and include an automated check, whether the interaction succeeded or not... but this is at the start, in the middle and/or at the end of every test; basically on every interaction with an object on the page).

I'm a bit lost by now (read and tried too many not working approaches).
I did find [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34397983/8683679), but fail to make it a working solution for my problem.

I am grateful for any further hints or examples, how I can take a screenshot at the exact moment when the `expect()` fails.

Comment: Hello! did you check this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-reporter-2 for me it takes a screenshot only when my expect fails, maybe you can find the answer there